# Product of Topological Manifolds

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

If M and N are topological manifolds, then their product is a topological manifold.

I can show that the product manifold is locally Euclidean, but I'm not sure how to show it is Hausdorff and second countable.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The product of two second-countable topological spaces $X$ and $Y$ is always second countable, because if $U_i, V_j$ are bases for $X,Y$ then $U_i \times V_j$ is a basis for $X \times Y$.

Indeed, by definition of basis we want to prove that given a point $(x,y)\ in W$ where $W$ is an open set of $X \times  Y$, we can find a basic open set $U_i \times V_j \subseteq W$ with $(x,y) \in U_i \times V_j$. By the definition of the product topology we can find open subsets $U,V$ of $X,Y$ such that $(x,y)\in U \times V \subseteq W$. Now use the second countability of $X$ and $Y$.

The product of two hausdorff spaces $X,Y$ is always hausdorff because if $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2) \in X \times Y$ are distinct points then WLOG $x_1 \neq x_2$, so we can separate $x_1$ from $x_2$ using some disjoint open sets $U_1,U_2$ of $X$. Now $U_1 \times Y, U_2 \times Y$ separate the original points.